# Unable to detect suitable environment

Tags: orchardcms, visual-studio-2015, orchardcms-1.9

I am trying to deploy my Orchard 1.9.2 project but when I run ClickToBuild I get this error. I have no clue about batch scripting but I figure it's because the batch file is trying to look for Visual Studio 11.0 or 12.0 but I'm running Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. Even so, the files that are being referenced here don't exist in my Visual Studio 14.0 folder either.

I have no idea how to proceed.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enhance the **ClickToBuild.cmd** like this

```
FOR %%b in (
       "%VS140COMNTOOLS%..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
       "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
       "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" 

       "%VS120COMNTOOLS%..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
       "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
       "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" 

       "%VS110COMNTOOLS%..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
       "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
       "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" 
    ) do (
    if exist %%b ( 
       call %%b x86
       goto build
    )
)

echo "Unable to detect suitable environment. Build may not succeed."

:build

SET target=%1
SET project=%2

IF "%target%" == "" SET target=Build
IF "%project%" =="" SET project=Orchard.proj

lib\nuget\nuget.exe restore .\src\Orchard.sln

msbuild /t:%target% %project%

pause
```

It seems the 1.9.2 Branch has no updated ClickToBuild.cmd yet.
However, the updated batch file is present in [1.10.0 and dev](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/blob/1.10/ClickToBuild.cmd)

Comment: This is what I needed. I also had to actually install the Visual C++ compiler as it isn't installed by default apparently.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `clicktobuild`, but should use `build Precompiled` instead. See http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Building-and-deploying-Orchard-from-a-source-code-drop for full instructions on how to build from the command-line if you can't use Visual Studio.

Comment: What are the notable differences between `clicktobuild` and `build Precompiled`? I'm using shared hosting and I have to admit I wasn't really sure on which of the resulting folders/files I needed to upload.

Comment: clicktobuild does all kinds of things, such as running tests, that you don't need to do routinely as you build. It also produces more than you need, and doesn't make it easy to see what you need to deploy. Build precompiled on the other hand is designed to produce the ready to deploy version.

Comment: "and doesn't make it easy to see what you need to deploy." That's exactly the problem I had when I finally managed to get through the build process. Thanks for pointing me in the right way!